# Multivariable chain rule for $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},\ f\ \ \mathcal{C}^2$ function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^2.$ Let $F\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}=f\begin{pmatrix}r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$. Show that $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \theta^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2},$ here the lefthand side is evaluated at $\begin{bmatrix}r\\\theta\end{bmatrix}$ and the righthand is evaluated at $\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta\\r\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}.$

What I have done:
$DF\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}=Df\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)D\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}=\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)\ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)\right] \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta & r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)\cos\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)\sin\theta & -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)r\sin\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(\vec{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\\theta\end{pmatrix}\right)r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial F}{\partial\theta}\end{bmatrix}.$

It is not clear to me now how I should apply the chain rule to compute the left hand side terms like $\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial r^2}$ so I would appreciate an hint about how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F(r,\theta)=f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$. Applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case), we get
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin(\theta),\quad \frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}=-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}r\sin(\theta)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\cos(\theta).$$
The above equations follow also from your work.

Now we differentiate again (recall that $f\in C^2$ and therefore [mixed partial derivative are equal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)):
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial r^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\cos^2(\theta)+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\sin^2(\theta),\\\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \theta^2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}r^2\sin^2(\theta)-2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}r^2\cos^2(\theta)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}r\cos(\theta)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}r\sin(\theta).$$
Finally, it easy to  verify that the required identity holds:
\begin{align}\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \theta^2}&=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\cos^2(\theta)+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\sin^2(\theta)\\
&\; +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cos(\theta)+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin(\theta)\\
&\; +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\sin^2(\theta)-2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\cos^2(\theta)\\
&\;-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\sin(\theta)\\
&=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for you very thorough answer. What puzzles me are the two terms $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}$ in $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial r^2}$. I know the chain rule, namely that if $\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{g(a)}$ then 
$\mathbf{D}(\mathbf{f}\circ\mathbf{g})(\mathbf{a})]=[\mathbf{Df(g(a))}]\circ [\mathbf{Dg(a)}].$ but I don't see how it gives me those two terms (although the $\cos^2$ and $\sin^2$ terms are clear.

Comment: Moreover $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is a shorthand of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$

Comment: @lorenzo I realized that I missed the mixed partial derivatives. I fixed it.

Comment: thanks. Would it be reasonable to find these derivatives by applying again the chain rule theorem again to $\mathbf{D(f\circ g)}$? Would I get $\mathbf{D(f\circ g)}=\mathbf{[D(Df(g(a))][Dg(a)]+[Df(g(a)][D(D(g(a))]}$? I would like to see how higher derivatives are found by repeated application of the chain rule in matrix form, if at all possible. Thanks.

Comment: @lorenzo We find second derivatives because we apply the chain rule to the first derivatives.
Repeated applications of the chain rule lead to the Faà di Bruno's formula. See here for the multivariate version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula#Multivariate_version

Comment: understood, thanks